# Map.Entry entry and lambda expression cannot be resolved

Tags: java

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. ForEach() with lambda expression "entry cannot be resolved" on Eclipse Luna and even on CMD.

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {          
            String str = sc.nextLine().replaceAll("\\s+", "").replaceAll("\\r\\n+", "");
            char[] arr = str.toCharArray();  
            len += arr.length;                

           for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
                char ch = str.charAt(i);
                if(map.containsKey(ch))          
                   map.put(ch, map.get(ch) + 1); 
                else
                    map.put(ch, 1);                 
           }

            map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry. <Character, Integer> comparingByValue().reversed())
            .limit(5)
            .forEach(entry -> System.out.printf("'%c' : %d%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce using Dcoder (IDE for Android devices) - does not result in compiler errors for me. Try a [clean & rebuild](https://coderanch.com/t/528330/ide/Project-Clean-Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

it working find to me until 5 characters in string without spaces more than 5 character it throw following exception

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at com.rmi.service.imp.MyServcieImp.main(MyServcieImp.java:29)`

this is your code

`public class MyServcieImp {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int len=0;
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {          
        String str = sc.nextLine().replaceAll("\\s+", "").replaceAll("\\r\\n+", "");
        char[] arr = str.toCharArray();  
        len += arr.length;                

       for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            char ch = str.charAt(i);
            if(map.containsKey(ch))          
               map.put(ch, map.get(ch) + 1); 
            else
                map.put(ch, 1);                 
       }

        map.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry. <Character, Integer> comparingByValue().reversed())
        .limit(5)
        .forEach(entry -> System.out.printf("'%c' : %d%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    }
}
```

} `

what you want? to print more than 5 or what ?

if you want to print all string length as u want just replace

`char ch = str.charAt(i);`

and

`map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry. <Character, Integer> comparingByValue().reversed())
            .limit(5)
            .forEach(entry -> System.out.printf("'%c' : %d%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));`

with 
`char ch = arr[i];`

and

`map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry. <Character, Integer> comparingByValue().reversed())
            .limit(map.size())
            .forEach(entry -> System.out.printf("'%c' : %d%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));`

and print what you want. :)

Comment: It is duplicate char count. Not printing the entire string length. The trouble this " entry cannot be resolved". See output : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 entry cannot be resolved to a variable
 Syntax error on token "-", -- expected
 entry cannot be resolved
 entry cannot be resolved

Comment: Please provide me your input and exception output in code form to easy to notify it

Comment: /** input line  */                                                                                                      File f = new File("The three did feed the deer 
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);        
      /** below is console output */                                                              Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 entry cannot be resolved to a variable
 Syntax error on token "-", -- expected
 entry cannot be resolved
 entry cannot be resolved

Comment: u need to take input from file or from console 
i tried from console and here get the following result 



`The three did feed the deer The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog`



out put:
`'e' : 12
'd' : 6
'h' : 5
'o' : 4
'r' : 4
't' : 3
'T' : 2
'f' : 2
'i' : 2
'u' : 2
'a' : 1
'b' : 1
'c' : 1
'g' : 1
'j' : 1
'k' : 1
'l' : 1
'm' : 1
'n' : 1
'p' : 1
'q' : 1
'v' : 1
'w' : 1
'x' : 1
'y' : 1
'z' : 1
`